# How to perform Parse query using relation where relation contains one or no objects matching conditions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery, pfrelation

I'm using the Parse iOS SDK in Objective-C and trying to query for objects based on whether an object's relation contains either at least one object matching a particular query or has no relational objects matching that same query. I'm trying to use `-[PFQuery whereKey:matchesQuery:]` and `-[PFQuery whereKey:doesNotMatchQuery:]` to do this but I'm getting the error `"bad type for $inQuery"` and believe that this is related to what I'm trying to do. Is there a way to be able to query for such objects in a single PFQuery? If not, what is the best way of accomplishing this?

I found the following existing answer from the old Parse forums that uses `-[PFQuery whereKey:containedIn:]`, but it appears to use an array of PFObjects rather than a PFRelation for its key and also requires an existing array of objects to match against (and therefore didn't appear to work for me): https://www.parse.com/questions/query-where-relation-contains-any-object-from-array

**Example:**

Let's say that I have two classes of PFObjects: `Teacher` and `Student`. A Teacher has a to-many PFRelation `students` to Student, while each Student has properties `firstName` and `lastName`, each of which take a string. I want to be able to query for Teachers based on properties of their Students, e.g.:

- All teachers that have at least one student named `Billy`.
- All teachers that have no students named `Emily'.

To do this I am currently using the following code to search for teachers with at least one student named "Billy":

```
PFQuery *teacherQuery = [[PFQuery alloc] initWithClassName:@"Teacher"];
PFQuery *studentsQuery = [[PFQuery alloc] initWithClassName:@"Student"];
[studentsQuery whereKey:@"firstName" equalTo:@"Billy"];
[teacherQuery whereKey:@"students" matchesQuery:studentsQuery];
```

and the following code to search for teachers with no students named "Emily":

```
PFQuery *teacherQuery = [[PFQuery alloc] initWithClassName:@"Teacher"];
PFQuery *studentsQuery = [[PFQuery alloc] initWithClassName:@"Student"];
[studentsQuery whereKey:@"firstName" notEqualTo:@"Emily"];
[teacherQuery whereKey:@"students" matchesQuery:studentsQuery];
```

Comment: Just noticed this in the documentation – apparently `-[PFQuery whereKey:matchesQuery:]` "only works where the key’s values are PFObjects or arrays of PFObjects." Does this mean that it doesn't work when the key is a PFRelation?

Answer (score -1):

You can actually query the `PFRelation` itself. I imagine it would be something like:

```
PFObject *teacher = ...// teacher object you got from query
PFRelation *students = [teacher relationForKey:@"students"];
[students whereKey:@"first_name" equalTo:@"Billy"];
```

Not easy for me to test myself right now but maybe you could use that as a subquery? I would be interested to know if you ever solved this.

Comment: You can't call (whereKey) on PFRelation. you should make query first